# Stormpath Express Google authentication force username on registration

Tags: authentication, express, stormpath

I have a Stormpath / Express simple application and have the Google authentication working.  However, **username** is essential to my app, and I don't want jsmith@gmail.com to be the username but rather a **unique username** that the user chooses when they register (their first login with Google account).  Is this possible with Stormpath? Thanks, (*I assume any solution will apply to Facebook etc.*)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Once the user has logged in with Google login, you can collect any custom username you want from the user, and update the Stormpath Account object with this username field =)

For instance (inside of a route):

```
req.user.username = 'some-new-username';
req.user.save(err => {
  if (err) throw err;
  res.send('Updated username!');
});
```

Comment: could this code also run in the `postLoginHandler`? Thanks.